# Non-linear optimization in Cplex

Tags: cplex, nonlinear-optimization

Is the following type of problem solvable in `cplex`?

```
minimize mT

subject to
mT - 2214.44 x1 - 168.5 x2 - 1874.75 x3=0
110722.0 x1>=29.75 mT
110722.0 x1<=30.25 mT
8425.0 x2>=14.75 mT
8425.0 x2<=15.25 mT
93737.5 x3>=4.75 mT
93737.5 x3<=5.25 mT

Bounds
x1>=0
x2>=0
x3>=0
mT>=0

Integer
x1
x2
x3

end
```

Constraints are nonlinear in nature. I also tried `110722.0 x1/mT>=29.75` format. Any help?

Comment: Looks linear to me.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen, True. This is just a bad example.

Answer (score 0):

within CPLEX you also can rely on constraint programming.
And with CPOptimizer you do not need any linearity property.

For instance, in OPL you can write

```
using CP;

dvar int x in 1..100;
dvar int y in 1..100;

maximize x+y;
subject to
{
  x*y+log(y)<=10;
}
```

but you could do the same with all APIs such as C++, python, java ...